# Why PHP Server showing error on include() and required_once() functions?

Tags: php, url, webserver

I am using the php page includes in my site, it's perfectly working without error in localhost, but at the time of running this with a live web server it shows the error.
with using these functions
`include("http-url/file.php")` and `required_once("http-url/file.php")`
they are shows error like this

> Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   www.mysite.com/....
>    with file inclution.........
>   what to do to solve this issue

Comment: Are you using `http://` in the `include` function?

Comment: Even if it is very specific task and you need include files by http, you see error and answer in message "Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0". So - what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many developers include files by pointing to a remote URL, even if the file is within the local system. For example:

```
<?php include("http://example.com/includes/example_include.php"); ?>
```

With allow_url_include disabled, this method does not work. Instead, the file must be included with a local path, and there are three methods of doing this:

1. By using a relative path, such as ../includes/example_include.php.
2. By using an absolute path (also known as relative-from-root), such as /home/username/example.com/includes/example_include.php.
3. By using the PHP environment variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], which returns the absolute path to the web root directory. This is by far the best (and most portable) solution. The following example shows the environment variable in action.

**Example Include**

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/example_include.php"); ?>
```

More about **allow_url_include** [here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Allow_url_include)

Comment: i am using include in www.mysite1.com, but the included file is located in www.mysite2.com. so only i am using this http link.....

Comment: Oh, If you still want to include remote files, you can set: allow_url_include = On but seriously, I recommend you should not do that because of security risks. Unfortunately the above way does not work for a host in another location.

Comment: can i use it with document.location in javascript